# Sum of last 7 days

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get sum of qty of last 7 days. My table had missing days which I input. Sample data looks as below:

| order_date | qty | customer_id | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 12345 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 123456 |

My code is shown below. I get rolling sum out of it instead of sum of last 7 days and I cannot figure out what is wrong with it.

```
DECLARE @startdate date = '2023-03-25';
DECLARE @enddate date = '2023-04-11';

WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT @startdate AS order_date
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEADD(dd, 1, order_date)
    FROM cte
    WHERE DATEADD(dd, 1, order_date) <= @enddate
)
SELECT b.order_date, qty, customer_id, product_id
    , SUM(qty) OVER (PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY b.order_date ROWS BETWEEN 6 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS sum_qty
FROM zadanie5 AS a
RIGHT JOIN cte b
    ON a.order_date = b.order_date
ORDER BY order_date
```

I would really appreciate you advice.

Comment: This should be a simple WHERE order_date >= DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, 0, getdate()) - 7, 0) to get the last 7 days.  Then SUM(qty) and GROUP BY on the necessary columns.

Comment: Please send your example and expected with text

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with sample days and desired results

Answer (score 0):

A way is to do a triangular join:

```sql
declare @t table (
    customer_id int, product_id int, qty int, order_date datetime
)

insert into @t 
values  (1, 1, 10, getdate())
,   (1, 1, 5, getdate() - 1)
,   (1, 1, 2, getdate() - 3)
,   (1, 1, 2, getdate() - 6)
,   (1, 1, 12, getdate() - 7)
,   (1, 1, 12, getdate() - 10);

SELECT a.order_date, qty, customer_id, product_id
    , (select SUM(qty) from @t as b where b.customer_id = a.customer_id and b.product_id = a.product_id and b.order_date between a.order_date - 7 and a.order_date)
FROM @t AS a
ORDER BY order_date
```

It's not the most performant query, unless you have good indexes on the joined fields.

A windowed approach would be to do LAG(qty, 1) over(...) + LAG(qty, 2) over(...)  etc, but suspect it might have worse performance